# Soft deleting a many-to-many relationship's pivot in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is there a way to 'soft delete' a many-to-many relationship? I've already added a `deleted_at` column to my pivot table and am using the `SoftDeletingTrait`. But when you `detach` the two relationships, the row is completely deleted.

I have the tables `clients`, `users` and `client_user`. I am hoping that somehow, using `User::find($user_id)->detach($client_id)` would not actually delete the pivot row, but set the deleted_at to the current timestamp.

And then continuing after this, I don't want to be able to get soft-deleted items back. However, at the moment, even if I manually set the value of `deleted_at`, I still get the result

Comment: My question is - why would you want to soft-delete it? That's the kind of data you can easily get back. Soft deleting is used as a mechanism for data that you just don't want to lose, even if it's been deleted intentionally - such as clients, and users.

Comment: @Oddman, okay maybe the examples of the tables I gave were bad. But what I actually have is a request table that a client creates and then sends it to all users. I want to then soft-delete the pivot once a user has completed a request to have a record of when people submitted their requests

Comment: I would guess all you need is custom pivot model using `SoftDeletingTrait` - have you tried?

Comment: Yes I did, it still deletes the row. `SoftDeletingTrait` doesn't work on pivot tables.

Comment: @Kousha Yes, in fact there is no way to do it without custom relation object handling all the stuff you need.

Comment: SoftDeletingTrait only works on the model, not the pivot tables. You'd need to setup a custom model that represents the pivot table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DB::table('client_user')
                ->where('client_id', $client->id)
                ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->update(array('deleted_at' => DB::raw('NOW()')));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class User extend Model
{

    public function clients(): Relation
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(
                Client::class,
                'client_user',
                'user_id',
                'client_id'
            )
            ->using(ClientUserPivot::class)
            ->wherePivot('deleted_at', null)
            // load pivot ID (otherwise deleted event won't fire)
            // load more pivot fileds if we need
            ->withPivot('id', 'is_enabled', 'extra') 
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

}

/* The Cilent model file, in a similar way */
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class Client extend Model
{

    public function users(): Relation
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(
                User::class,
                'client_user',
                'client_id',
                'user_id'
            )
            ->using(ClientUserPivot::class)
            ->wherePivot('deleted_at', null)
            // load pivot ID (otherwise deleted event won't fire)
            // load more pivot fileds if we need
            ->withPivot('id', 'is_enabled', 'extra') 
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

}

/* The Pivot file */
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ClientUserPivot extends Pivot
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $incrementing = true;

    protected $table = 'client_user';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function client(): Relation
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function user(): Relation
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

/////////////////////////
// We can see that the Pivot class is extends Model class,
// it just use the AsPivot trait, set the $incrementing = false,
// and set the $guarded = [].

// So, we can run the methods of Model in Pivot entity, such as @delete.
// Working:
$user = User::find(1);
$client = $user->clients->firstWhere('id', $clientId);
if ($client) {
    $client->pivot->delete();
}

// Last:
// You may have seen that I added a 'is_enabled' field in the pivot table,
// I think it may better than SoftDeletes.
```

Comment: Add some text also to show how your code is working.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, without the ->using() bit which threw an error

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a softdelete on a pivot table, all you need is to gave them their own id and timestamps. That way "SoftDeletingTrait" can work. It is a little tricky, but it works for me.
Edit:

And i also forget to mention that you have to make a model for the pivot table, as someone told you above =P By example, you have a credit line, and many requeriments for that credit line, that are used on many credit_lines, but you wanna know the status of that requeriments on each line, and also deleted from that credit line but not from others.

```
Table
credit_line
id
name
capital
[More columns]
Table
requirements (Documents and things that everybody uses)
id
name
[More columns]

Table (pivot)

credit_line_has_requirements
id <---- you need this...
timestamps <---- also this
status_id <---- declined, accepted etc... 
reason <---- a text description of why you declined or acepted the requeriment...
```

then you make a model for CreditLineHasRequeriments using that pivot table.

Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use softDeletes trait in pivot table, you have to extend your pivot modal vai Laravel's regular modal instead of Pivot i.e.

```
YourPivotModal extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; instead of 

YourPivotModal extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
```

Also the deleted_at column must be defined in pivot table